# How to Compare Two Datatable and get common records in other DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datatable

I have Two `DataTable` with Two columns in each `Table`. Now, i want to Compare these Two `DataTable` and the Matching rows in Third `DataTable` in C#.

Eg:

```
DataTableA
ColA1   ColA2
 1      sampletext1
 2      sampletext2
 4      sampletext4

DataTableB
ColB1   ColB2
 1      sampletext1
 2      sampletext2
 3      sampletext3

DataTableC
ColC1  ColC2
 1      sampletext1
 2      sampletext2
```

I have tried it using for loop but it slows down. Any other alternative.

Comment: What is your criteria for matching? Also, you might want to post your existing code for loop.

Comment: How is it related to Linq-to-Entities? `DataTable` is an in-memory object.

Comment: hello @Jakub Konecki,Both Columns from tableA matching with both columns from tableB and if it matches get the row in third datatable..!

Comment: Now you have changed from L2Entities to L2SQL, it's still not clear how this is related to a database at all since a `DataTable` is just an object. The answer highly depends on it since you should do such things in the database if possible.

Comment: hello @TimSchmelter, just i want to specify that can we do it using Linq-to-sql. And previously by mistake it is being added! I apologize..!

Comment: hey check i already given it by LINQ

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly your matching criteria is.
below might be helpful.

refer [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1407a809-9551-4646-b74d-3dee3535249c/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-c)

```
public static DataTable CompareTwoDataTable(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{ 
  dt1.Merge(dt2);
  DataTable d3 = dt2.GetChanges();
  return d3;
}
```

Comment: Wow what a great and short solution. Though very old question, If you can help me same way same thing but the two DataTable i have to compare don't have same no. of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use like below. It will work faster

```
var matched = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                      join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<string>("sno") equals table2.Field<string>("sno")
                      where table1.Field<string>("name") == table2.Field<string>("name")
                      select table1;
        if (matched.Count()>0)
        {
            DataTable dtt = matched.CopyToDataTable();
        }
```

Dont forget to mention as answer if it helps.

Comment: How this will work faster? Faster than what? How did you test the performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<dt1.rows.count;i++)
{
   if (dt2.rows.count > i)
    {
         if((dt1.rows[i][1] == dt2.rows[i][1])  && (dt1.rows[i][2] == dt2.rows[i][2]))
           {
               dt3.rows.add(dt.rows[i])
           } 

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First use merge function merge two datatable, and finnaly for loop on datatable and find result by select function:

```
dt1 = dt.Copy();
dt1.Merge(dt2);

//Here match condition third Data table
for(int i=0; i <=dt1.rows; i++)
{
  DataRow[] foundRows = dt3.Select("page_name='" + dt1.[i]['colname'] + "'");
  //function or code here;
}
```